# Unable to figure out SQL query for a task

Tags: sql-server

I have database with following tables

Login table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Login]
(
    [username] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [user_type] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [isDelete] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isDelete] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

Questions table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions]
(
    [Qid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Qtype] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Question] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [isDelete] [bit] NULL,
)
```

- `Login.id` is a foreign key and references `Test.UserId`
- `Test.TestId` is foreign key and references `Questions.Tid`

My question is: I want to fetch `Login.username`, `Test.TestName` and the number of questions per test, e.g. I want all tests present and number of questions per test (even if 0).

I tried the following query

```
select 
    Test.TestId, Test.TestName, COUNT(Questions.Tid) as 'No.Of Questions' 
from 
    Test, Questions
where  
    Test.TestId = Questions.Tid and
    Questions.isDelete <> 'true'
group by 
    TestId, TestName
```

but this query only returns the tests for which at least single question is present in questions table.

I want all tests compulsory and then questions per test.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  Please do not use both tags, as syntax is usually subtly different and you just waste people's time.

Comment: it is Sql Server. Sorry to include both tags

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `Left outer join`

```
select T.TestId,T.TestName,COUNT(Q.Tid) as [No.Of Questions]
from Test t
Left Join Questions q
       On Q.isDelete<>'true'
      and T.TestId=Q.Tid
group by TestId,TestName
```

your current syntax works like `Inner Join`. Thats the reason you are getting tests which is not having any questions